# Touch and open file in same command alias

Tags: scripting, osx, alias

I find myself typing these commands a lot (on Mac):

```
$ touch example.txt
$ open example.txt
```

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this. I tried this:

```
$ alias t='touch $0 && open $0’
```

But I got this:

```
$ t awef.txt
touch: illegal option -- b
```

Note: I do not want to empty the file. If the file already has content, I just want to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an alias. They are extremely limited and, for example, won't let you interpolate an argument into the definition. Instead, use a function:

```
t() { [[ ! -f "$1" ]] && touch "$1"; open "$1"; }
```

This creates (touches) a file only if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like this but couldn't find it.